# testing stripe with stripe.js in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, coffeescript, stripe-payments

My app uses the `stripe.js` java library to generate the `stripe_card_token` same as ryan bates [did here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/288-billing-with-stripe?view=asciicast).

I'm trying to add unit tests to my controller and I'm getting troubles in the generation of the token. I couldn't find the function to generate the token anywhere in the Stripe API, as it seems to be available only in the javascript.

How can I generate the stripe_token in the test?

Here's the part of the controller dealing with stripe:

```
def save_with_payment!
    if valid?
      customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
        description: "#{user.email} - #{user.id} - #{billing_name}", 
        email:  billing_email,
        plan: plan,
        card: stripe_card_token)
      self.stripe_customer_token = customer.id
      plan = validate_actual_plan customer.subscriptions.data[0].plan.id
      save!
    end

  rescue Stripe::InvalidRequestError => e
    logger.error "Stripe error while creating customer: #{e.message}"
    errors.add :base, "There was a problem with your credit card. 
      Your card wasn't charged. #{e.message}"
    return false
  end
```

Here's the controller:

```
  def create

    @subscription = Subscription.new(params[:subscription])
    @subscription.user_id = current_user.id
    @subscription.expiration_date = 1.month.from_now
    @subscription.stripe_card_token = params[:subscription][:stripe_card_token]
    respond_to do |format|
      if @subscription.save_with_payment!
        if current_user.upgrade_plan :premium
          format.html { redirect_to user_trades_path(current_user), notice: 'Subscription was successfully created. Compliments you are now subscribed to the premium plan' }
          format.json { render json: user_trades_path(current_user), status: :created, location: @subscription }
        else
          format.html { redirect_to home_pricing_path, notice: 'Error while upgrading your account, please contact us' }
          format.json { render json: home_pricing_path, status: :created, location: @subscription }
        end
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @subscription.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

This is the Coffeescript generating the token:

```
  processCard: ->
    card =
      number: $(page.cardNumber).val()
      cvc: $(page.cardCode).val()
      expMonth: $(page.cardMonth).val()
      expYear: $(page.cardYear).val()
    Stripe.card.createToken(card, @handleStripeResponse)
```

Here's the test:

```
  test "should create subscription" do
    begin
      StripeMock.start

      card = {
        number: "4242424242424242",
        cvc: "123",
        expMonth: 1.month.from_now.month,
        expYear: 1.year.from_now.year,
      }

      token = Stripe.card.createToken(card)

      assert_difference('Subscription.count') do
        post :create, subscription: { 
          billing_email: @subscription.billing_email,
          billing_city: @subscription.billing_city, 
          billing_country: @subscription.billing_country, 
          billing_name: @subscription.billing_name, 
          billing_street2: @subscription.billing_street2, 
          billing_street: @subscription.billing_street, 
          billing_zip: @subscription.billing_zip,
          stripe_card_token: token,
          plan: @subscription.plan }
      end

      assert_redirected_to subscription_path(assigns(:subscription))
    ensure
      StripeMock.stop
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured that creating the token was indeed possible with the Stripe API, as described here:

https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_card_token

I had also found an issue with the plan I was going to subscribe, because I'm using StripeMock, there's no connection to the real/test stripe at all. this means that my mock doesn't know about the plans I try to subscribe.

I had to generate a little function to generate the plan as well.

here's its code:

```
  def create_plan
    plan = {
      :amount => 1800,
      :interval => 'month',
      :name => 'premium',
      :currency => 'gbp',
      :id => 'premium'
    }

    response = Stripe::Plan.create plan
  end
```